# Difference between "phenomenological" and "empirical"

Tags: synonyms, science

Models in science are sometimes called "phenomenological" and sometimes "empirical." Looking at the definitions of these two words, I feel like they are really saying the same thing: that the model is informed by experimental results rather than derived from first principles. Is this correct, or is there a distinction I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empirical models need not have any theory. A phenomenological model would have some theory in which the relevant phenomena are presupposed, but no theory that explains where these phenomena come from.